# Do delta wing gliders respawn after using?

Tags: far-cry-4

I've used a delta wing glider. Does it make a difference landing it properly or jump from it during the flight or even crash it?

Will the delta wing glider respawn anyway at the same original point after some time?

Comment: I haven't played enough to say for sure, but in Far Cry 3 they did always respawn after some time. Crashing or landing didn't matter.

Comment: Same here. I *have* reused buzzers spawned at the same location multiple times, however. Is the delta wing glider different from all the hang gliders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the gliders that you can try like, say, in Banapur?

They do respawn, yes. There is no difference between landing properly and letting go midair